# woocommerce_add_to_cart throwing 'Maximum function nesting level of '256'' error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stack-overflow, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create a plugin that will pull products from a category into a dropdown on other products in a different category and then add both products to the cart.

Based on the selected product, the main product SKU will change and be passed through to the cart/checkout and order pages.

The problem I am running into is that when I select a product in the dropdown and click add to cart, I get an error of "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /Local Sites/woocommerce-test-site/app/public/wp-includes/option.php on line 81".

Line 81 of options.php is:

```
if ( is_scalar( $option ) ) {
   $option = trim( $option );
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
function get_current_category() {
    global $post;

    // Initialize array for product categories
    $current_cats = array();
    $cat_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');

    // Get main product category names
    foreach ($cat_terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_name = $term->name;
        // Assign category names to array
        $current_cats[] = $product_cat_name;
    }
    return $current_cats;
}

// Display Compressor Location Field in 'Compressor Kits'  
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_compressor_location');
function add_compressor_location() {
    $current_cats = get_current_category();

    if (in_array('Compressor Kits', $current_cats)) {
        woocommerce_wp_select(
            array(
                'id' => 'compressor_location',
                'label' => __('Compressor Location', 'woocommerce'),
                'options' => array(
                    '' => __('choose', 'woocommerce'),
                    'L8' => __('L8', 'woocommerce'),
                    'L6' => __('L6', 'woocommerce'),
                    'R8' => __('R8', 'woocommerce'),
                    'R6' => __('R6', 'woocommerce')
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}

// Save Compressor Location 
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_compressor_location');
function save_compressor_location($post_id) {
    $compressor_location_select = $_POST['compressor_location'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'compressor_location', esc_attr($compressor_location_select));
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'compressor_kit_dropdown');
function compressor_kit_dropdown() {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    $current_cats = get_current_category();

    if (in_array('Complete A/C Systems', $current_cats)) {
        // create array of category products
        $args = array(
            'category'      => 'compressor-kits',
            'limit'         => -1,
        );

        $comp_product_array = wc_get_products($args); // Retrieve products

        // Check if category products array is not empty 
        if (!empty($comp_product_array)) {

            // Loop thru product array
            foreach ($comp_product_array as $products) {

                // Initialize array for product tags
                $tags_array =  array();
                $product_tags = wp_get_post_terms($products->get_id(), 'product_tag', array('fields' => 'names')); // Get array of Product tags 
                $tags_array = $product_tags; // Assign product tags to array    

                if (array_intersect($tags_array, $current_cats)) {

                    $product_id = $products->get_id(); // Get product ID
                    $product_price = " +$" . $products->get_regular_price(); // Get product price
                    $product_name = $products->get_name(); // Get product name
                    $product_sku = $products->get_sku(); // Get product SKU
                    $product_meta = $products->get_meta('compressor_location'); // Get product meta

                    $options[$product_id . $product_meta] = $product_name . ' - ' . $product_meta; // Display product as name + price
                }
            }

            $options = array(
                0 => __('Select an option...', 'woocommerce'),
                1 => __('No Compressor & Bracket ', 'woocommerce')
            ) + $options;

            // Add select field
            woocommerce_form_field('compressor-options', array(
                'type'          => 'select',
                'label'         => __('Add Compressor & Bracket', $domain),
                'required'      => false,
                'options'       => $options,
            ), '');
            echo '<p>Number of Compressor & Bracket options: ' . count($options) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_compressor_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function add_compressor_to_cart() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['compressor-options'] ) ) {
        // Get product ID
        $the_product_id = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['compressor-options'] );

        // WC Cart
        if ( WC()->cart ) {
            // Get cart
            $cart = WC()->cart;

            // If cart is NOT empty
            if ( ! $cart->is_empty() ) {
                // Cart id
                $product_cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id( $the_product_id );

                // Find product in cart
                $in_cart = $cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

                // If product NOT in cart
                if ( ! $in_cart ) {
                    $cart->add_to_cart( $the_product_id );
                }
            } else {
                $cart->add_to_cart( $the_product_id );
            }
            return $the_product_id;
        }
    }
}
```

The custom field info is then passed to the cart and appended to the end of the main product SKU.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_compressor_location_data', 10, 3);
function add_compressor_location_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    $compressor_option = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'compressor-options');

    if (! empty($compressor_option) ) {
        $cart_item_data['compressor-options'] = substr($compressor_option, -2);
        return $cart_item_data;
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'compressor_location_cart_field', 10, 2);
function compressor_location_cart_field($title, $cart_item) {
    global $product;

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    if (is_cart() || is_checkout() && $product->get_sku()) {

        if (!empty($cart_item['compressor-options'])) {
            $compressor_location = $cart_item['compressor-options'];
        }

        $sku = '<br/>SKU: ' . $product->get_sku();

        echo $title;
        echo $sku . $compressor_location;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing haha. I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: could you have an infinite loop somehow?

Comment: @David, yes. Thank you. I was concerned with the information and not realizing that `add_to_cart()` is being called inside of the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` action. I am guessing that I will need to break out of that once the product has been added to the cart.